# How to display 1 full article and the a summary of others

Tags: theming

Hi I'm new to Drupal and I'm trying to find a way to display on my home page the full version of the latest article and a list of other articles as teasers.
The teasers could be either listed under the full article or in a block in the sidebar. Is this possible? Currently I can only list articles as teasers.

Comment: Check out views.  You can create a views block that shows the latest full article and then add an attachment that shows your teasers.  You would be able to put the block anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create two views block.

Create a views block for latest article like this way

```
  under Format, select content (full content) in show filed.
  select update date field in filter criteria.
  In Advanced Options,  under Pager ' Display a specified number of items' as 1
```

Create another views block for other article like this way

```
  under Format, select content (teaser) in show filed.
  select update date field in filter criteria.
  In Advanced Options,  under Pager 'your choice' and set offset value as 1
```

Now display the blocks where you want.

Answer (score 1):

Install [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), then enable the disabled view called `Front page`.

To get two different view modes for the nodes, you could add an attachment display to the view that shows a single latest article in full view mode and add it to the view at the top. Then you would set the page display (the original view) to display teasers, starting at an offset of 1.

It could also be accomplished with [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds).